# PhP cURL - 403 Error With API Key In Header

Tags: php, curl

I'm relatively new to cURL in PHP, and I'm looking to cURL against an API where where the API Key is in the header. Here's what I have thus far:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://publicapi.ohgo.com/api/v1/reported-conditions?region=ne-ohio');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: APIKEY 016c348e-58fe-486f-ad72-9b2f41c55a56';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Unfortunately, after running this script, I get a 403 error printed to the screen after a few seconds:

```
Error:Failed connect to publicapi.ohgo.com:443; Connection timed out
```

How can I get these API results? Worth noting:

1) I have changed a few characters from my actual API key to make the one above

2) API documentation is here: https://publicapi.ohgo.com/docs/v1/swagger/index#/Reported32Conditions

Answer (score 0):

It's failed to connect to API server. Try to increase connect timeout for that.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); // value in seconds
```

Comment: Your answer is not suitable with the question.

Comment: I added that line, and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: @ThanhDao The above errors does not related to `Error API Key in Header`. @scotman1 That cannot make a connect with API server. Make sure you have put correct URL.

Comment: @Totoro I can confirm that both URLs in my original post are correct. See the cURL URL in the API documentation.

Comment: @scotman1 Does service down? I cannot access to them by any methods (browser, curl or something else.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip ssl verification this will solve your issue

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://publicapi.ohgo.com/api/v1/reported-conditions?region=ne-ohio');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Skip SSL Verification

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: APIKEY 016c348e-58fe-486f-ad72-9b2f41c55a56';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Error:Failed connect to publicapi.ohgo.com:443; Connection timed out is still the error.

Comment: @scotman1 I have tried to open your mentioned url but it is not opening please check and update url.